# How to avoid 'und' key in each field within entities returned by entity_load?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How to avoid 'und' key in each field within entities returned by entity_load? I realize it has something to do with localisation and simply using ['und'][0]['safe_value'] is not a good idea.

[image: How to avoid und index?]

What can I do to avoid 'und' indexes?

Comment: What do you mean by 'avoid' exactly? If you mean "how do I get rid of them?", you can't. You can use the `LANGUAGE_NONE` constant for more readable code, though

Comment: @Clive I mean not needing to write $node->field['und']['value'] and writing $node->field['value'] instead.

Comment: No you can't do that. You can use [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) or an [`EntityMetadataWrapper`](https://drupal.org/node/1021556) instead though, both will take care of language negotiation for you

Answer (score 1):

We need to save this in the format as:

$node->field[$node->language]['value'].

This will automatically take the value in future if use any language.

Comment: for $node->language should be set as current user or site language or you can set it as $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;